# Remember selected background and text colors highlights between activities

Tags: android, listview, colors, selector, highlight

I have several activities some of them have listviews. When items in those listview are clicked, the background and text colors are highlighted and the next activity is started. I have custom  back buttons to go back to previous activities. I was wondering if there is a way to keep the background and text colors highlights from previously pressed listview, when I click my back buttons. Here is a sample code:

```
public class Act1 extends Activity {
//code to create arrays and adapters, populate listview and so on 
ListView listParams = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvParams);
listParams.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
                    viewClicked.setSelected(true);
                    SelectedParam = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("SelectedParam", SelectedParam);
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent goToAct2= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Act2.class);
                    startActivity(goToAct2);
                }
            });
```

I have xml selectors to change the colors of the selected item (not shown here...). Now when i am in the second activity, I'd like to get back to the first activity so I attached a function to a goback button:

```
goBack(View V){
    Intent goToAct1 = new Intent(Act2.this, Act1.class);
    startActivity(goToAct1);
}
```

When I come back to activity1, I would like my listview to remember the previous selection and highlight it in the listview.  Now when I use the navigation keys on my phone the highlight is remembered... Is there a way to mimic that. Or perhaps there is a simpler way. Please help :)

Comment: Yes you can change the background color of the layout of the listitem when you come back to the activity. You have already stored the value of the listitem. Storing the id will be much benifitial.

Comment: `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)` can solve your problem.

Comment: Your first activity already stored in **[back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)**, so when you want to navigate back to activity1 from activity2, you just need finish activity2, by overriding method `onNavigateUp()` if you press actionbar's back button, or other function that releated to your **goback button**

Comment: Can you guys elaborate a little more please? An example would help for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onSavedInstanceState(...)` to save the selected position:

```
private static int selectedPos = -1;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("selected", selectedPos);

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
   selectedPos = savedInstanceState.getInt("selected");

}

//get seleted position when click item
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
                  ... ...
                  selectedPos = position;
                  ... ...
               }
```

Finally in your `getView(...)` of atapter, add lines:

```
  if(selectedPos == position)
       convertView.setSelected(true);
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean getView of adapter? I don't have that function.. I populate my adapter with:
adapterParams = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.text1,R.id.text1_name, Params); listParams.setAdapter(adapterParams);

Comment: The adapter for your ListView, which is custom ArrayAdapter, need override `getView(...)`

Comment: @Andre Bounames how is your issue, does this answer solve or help it